# drawing with cairo over a GtkBox not using GtkDrawingArea

Tags: c, gtk, cairo

I program my application in C using GTK+3 and cairo.

is there a way to draw a line on top of a Vertical GtkBox ?

the thing is that I need to mark an area with a line. the area is a row of a vertical GtkBox, which is not a GtkDrawingArea.

is that possible?

any information regarding the issue would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Anything tried yet? How about subclassing `GtkBox`, overwriting the default draw handler (no signal connect foo, that can't work as it is executed _before_ the default draw handler if I remember correctly, recheck that) and within that call your the default `GtkBox` `draw` handler and afterwards draw the line before exiting the `your_draw_handler` function? Just a thought.
Also, code? Note that I did not try this, I can only tell you what I stumbled upon when implementing custom widgets, not hacking existing ones.

Comment: hi! i didn't try anything yet. didn't have ideas where to start. you provided some good points. i'll check them out. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using glade in order to create the Gtk Vertical Box.

I connected a callback to the draw signal and I marked 'After' in glade which actually calls my callback after the basic drawing. which allows me to draw on top of the elements inside it.

as simple as that ;)